# Android ListView position

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

I'm developing a web browser and I've just added bookmarks. I want to add a context menu to the list view to open and delete the bookmarks. I've got the code in place but when I tap the context menu it opens / deletes the top item. I'm really struggling to get it just right.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Jack

Comment: Just added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this to get the ID of the selected bookmark:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    int position = info.position;
    Cursor selectedBookmark = (Cursor) mAdapter.getItem(position);

    int selectedBookmarkId = selectedBookmark.getInt(0); // index 0, assuming your first column is the ID

    / ...
}
```

After getting the ID, you can use it to delete the selected item from the DB:

```
long ret = mdb.delete("bookmark", "_id = ?", new String[]{Integer.toString(selectedBookmarkId)});
```